# Any performance impact with Java modules used in Scala programs?

Tags: java, scala

I have a specific question about Java modules that are used in Scala.  In a program where the Java module being imported is going to do a lot of the heavy lifting (i.e., converting lots of large *.pdf files to *.txt files, while keeping structure), is there much of a performance hit for the module not being written in Scala?

I am new to the language, and I have not developed the mental model just yet.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The Java-sourced module will run no slower (or faster) when called from Scala as would from a normal Java program.

This is because the Java module is not "run" by Scala or modified in any way. Rather, the Scala code that invokes such module is itself compiled to [Java bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) - then all the bytecode (that of both Java source and Scala source origins) is executed by the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

Comment: Unless you're using collections conversions.